# How to fix pylint warning "Abstract class not referenced"?

Tags: python, warnings, abstract-class, pylint

I have a Python class that raises "NotImplementedError" for a couple of methods and the class is inherited by a few other classes which are defined in their own files.

When I run Pylint on the file that has the abstract class, it always complains "Abstract class not referenced". I was wondering is it just Pylint being paranoid or there's actually something I do need to fix?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have in your class a method raising a `NotImplementedError` it is enough to make pylint think this is an abstract class.

As pylint check each file isolated from the rest of the project, if no one inherit from this class in the file it will raise this message.

If you want to desactivate it you'll have to put this comment before your class definition :

```
#pylint: disable=R0921
```

Comment: Better to `pylint` the entire module as a whole instead of disabling R0921, except if your module is really a library that actually provides the abstract class. (But then you should at least have tests that subclass it.)

Answer (score 6):

Pylint considers each file "self-contained", so when checking the file where you defined your abstract class, but no subclasses, it complains with R0921 (http://www.logilab.org/card/pylintfeatures).

In fact, the message type is "R", which stands for "refactor" (http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#pylint-output): Pylint is suggesting "good practice", but you can happily leave it like that.